# Floating point to fixed point in C

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, digital-filters, fixed-point

I've been trying to make a digital filter.
I've used the following transfer function to get my digital coefficients 
https://gyazo.com/00195ef119f0b2ff93fa5855715abdc9

Which i've then transfered to code using the direct form 1 with 2 2nd order sections. Which you can see down below in the code.

To get this into smaller coefficients i first divided each section by a10 and a20 to get smaller coefficients and making a10 and a20 1. The undivided coefficients can still be seen in the code as comments.

To then get the code in fixed point i tried multiplying each coefficient by 2^15 to use 16 bit integers and then dividing my end result by the same amount. However this does not seem to work.

Voltage is the reading of the ADC which is the input of the filter.
And this is a 4th order lowpass butterworth filter with a -3dB at 500hz

And the delays in the for loop can probably be done in a different faster way but i'm not sure how else to do this.

Also not sure if this is important but this is done on a 8bit atmega chip.

TLDR: How do i implement this in fixed point and can the for loop for the delays be done faster?

Kind regards Chris

```
double xA[3] = {0};
double yA[3] = {0};
double xB[3] = {0};
double yB[3] = {0};
double y2 = 0;
double y = 0;
xA[0] = voltage;
xB[0] = voltage;
    //2nd order

/*  
double a10 = 1.842071000613218e+09  
double a11 = -3.180260791197821e+09             
double a12 = 1.377668208188961e+09
double b10 = 9.869604401089357e+06
double b11 = 1.973920880217871e+07
double b12 = 9.869604401089357e+06

double a20 = 1.706052605083395e+09
double a21 = -3.180260791197821e+09
double a22 = 1.513686603718784e+09
double b20 = 9.869604401089357e+06
double b21 = 1.973920880217871e+07
double b22 = 9.869604401089357e+06


 */

// Coefficients for 2 2nd order filters.       
double a10 = 1      
double a11 = -1.72645939822                 
double a12 = 0.74789093782
double b10 = 0.0053578849
double b11 = 0.0107157698
double b12 = 0.0053578849

double a20 = 1
double a21 = -1.86410476542
double a22 = 0.88724497662
double b20 = 0.0057850528   
double b21 = 0.0115701056
double b22 = 0.0057850528



    y2 = b10* xA[0]+ b11 *xA[1]+ b12*xA[2]- a11*yA[1] - a12*yA[2]; // 1st 2nd order
    y2 = y2/a10;
    yA[0] = y2;

    y = b20* xB[0]+ b21 *xB[1]+ b22*xB[2]- a21*yB[1] - a22*yB[2];                       //2nd 2nd order
    y = y/a20;
    yB[0] = y;


    for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)                             // delay for 1st 2nd order
        xA[i] = xA[i-1];

        for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)
        yA[i] = yA[i-1];

        for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)                        // delay for 2nd 2nd order
        xB[i] = xB[i-1];

        for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)
        yB[i] = yB[i-1];

      voltage = y;
```

My fixed point attempt.

```
double xA[3] = {0};
double yA[3] = {0};
double xB[3] = {0};
double yB[3] = {0};
int32_t y2 = 0;
int32_t y = 0;
xA[0] = voltage;
xB[0] = voltage;

// Coefficients for 2 2nd order filters. 
// Times 2^15 for fixed point   
int16_t a10 = 16384

int16_t a11 = -28286                    
int16_t a12 = 12253
int16_t b10 = 88
int16_t b11 = 176
int16_t b12 = 88

int16_t a20 = 16384
int16_t a21 = -30541
int16_t a22 = 14537
int16_t b20 = 95
int16_t b21 = 190
int16_t b22 = 95



    y2 = b10* xA[0]+ b11 *xA[1]+ b12*xA[2]- a11*yA[1] - a12*yA[2]; // 1st 2nd order
    y2 = y2/a10;
    yA[0] = y2;

    y = b20* xB[0]+ b21 *xB[1]+ b22*xB[2]- a21*yB[1] - a22*yB[2];                       //2nd 2nd order
    y = y/a20;
    yB[0] = y;


    for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)                             // delay for 1st 2nd order
        xA[i] = xA[i-1];

        for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)
        yA[i] = yA[i-1];

        for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)                        // delay for 2nd 2nd order
        xB[i] = xB[i-1];

        for(uint8_t i = 2; i > 0; i--)
        yB[i] = yB[i-1];

      voltage = y*0.00006103515;// divided by 16384 or 2^14
```

3rd edit with ur example.  unsure about these lines in the example that you gave. and i removed the forloop at the bottom. The entire process is done using an interupt timer thus not using the forloop.

state_error = (short)(accumulator & 0x00003FFF);
accumulator = (long)state_error + (((long)state_y1)<<14);

Also the adc value cast to voltage should probably done at the bottom and instead the res from adc read should be used for the calculations as it makes no sense to use the voltage for calculations to me.

```
//ADC_voltage:
#define MAX_VALUE_ADC   2047                               // only 11 bits are used
#define VCC         3.30
#define VREF        (((double) VCC) / 1.6)                 // maximal value is 2.06125 V
//DAC
#define MAX_VALUE_DAC 4095
#define CAL_DAC 1.000  // Calibration value DAC

double xA[3] = {0};
double yA[3] = {0};
double xB[3] = {0};
double yB[3] = {0};
int32_t y2 = 0;
int32_t y = 0;

// Times 2^14 for fixed point   
int32_t a10 = 16384

int32_t a11 = -28286                    
int32_t a12 = 12253
int32_t b10 = 88
int32_t b11 = 176
int32_t b12 = 88

int32_t a20 = 16384
int32_t a21 = -30541
int32_t a22 = 14537
int32_t b20 = 95
int32_t b21 = 190
int32_t b22 = 95


ISR(TCE0_OVF_vect)              //TIMER Interupt
{

    double  voltage ;       // contains read in voltage (mVolts)
    int16_t res;            // contains read in adc value
    int16_t BinaryValue;    // contains value to write to DAC


    res = read_adc();           //Read out the ADC (PIN A2)
    voltage = (double) res * 1000 * VREF / (MAX_VALUE_ADC + 1);                 // Measured voltage in Volts.

    y2 = b10* xA[0]+ b11 *xA[1]+ b12*xA[2]- a11*yA[1] - a12*yA[2]; // 1st 2nd order
    y2 = y2/a10;    // is this necessary? without fixed point its 1/1
    yA[0] = y2;
    if (y2 > 0x1FFFFFFF)
       {
       y2 = 0x1FFFFFFF;     /* clip value */
       }
    if (y2 < -0x20000000)
       {
       y2 = -0x20000000;    /* clip value */
       }

    y = b20* xB[0]+ b21 *xB[1]+ b22*xB[2]- a21*yB[1] - a22*yB[2];                       //2nd 2nd order
    y = y/a20;    // same for this one
    yB[0] = y;
    if (y > 0x1FFFFFFF)
       {
       y = 0x1FFFFFFF;     /* clip value */
       }
    if (y < -0x20000000)
       {
       y = -0x20000000;    /* clip value */
       }

    xA[0] = voltage;                                                     // 1st 2nd order delays
    xA[2] = xA[1];
    xA[1] = xA[0];

    yA[2] = yA[1];
    yA[1] = yA[0];


    xB[0] = voltage;                                                    // 2d 2nd order delays
    xB[2] = xB[1];
    xB[1] = xB[0];

    yB[2] = yB[1];
    yB[1] = yB[0];

    voltage = (short)(y >>14);                                          // divided by 16384 or 2^14     voltage = y>>14
    BinaryValue =  voltage*((MAX_VALUE_DAC)/(VCC))*0.001*CAL_DAC ;      // Bitvalue
    DACB.CH0DATA = BinaryValue ;                                    //write &USBDataIn to DAC (PIN A10)
    while (!DACB.STATUS & DAC_CH0DRE_bm);
```

I've  changed the states to ints and now do the actual math with the adc res value instead of the voltage value which probably makes more sense. I've also removed the clipping if's. At this point i don't know how to improve any more.

```
//ADC_voltage:
#define MAX_VALUE_ADC   2047                               // only 11 bits are used
#define VCC         3.30
#define VREF        (((double) VCC) / 1.6)                 // maximal value is 2.06125 V
//DAC
#define MAX_VALUE_DAC 4095
#define CAL_DAC 1.000  // Calibration value DAC

int32_t xA[3] = {0};
int32_t yA[3] = {0};
int32_t xB[3] = {0};
int32_t yB[3] = {0};
int32_t y2 = 0;
int32_t y = 0;

// Times 2^14 for fixed point   
int32_t a10 = 16384
int32_t a11 = -28286                    
int32_t a12 = 12253
int32_t b10 = 88
int32_t b11 = 176
int32_t b12 = 88

int32_t a20 = 16384
int32_t a21 = -30541
int32_t a22 = 14537
int32_t b20 = 95
int32_t b21 = 190
int32_t b22 = 95

ISR(TCE0_OVF_vect)              //TIMER Interupt
{
    double  voltage ;       // contains read in voltage (mVolts)
    int16_t res;            // contains read in adc value
    int16_t BinaryValue;    // contains value to write to DAC
    res = read_adc();           //Read out the ADC (PIN A2)
    voltage = (double) res * 1000 * VREF / (MAX_VALUE_ADC + 1);     // Measured voltage in Volts.

    y2 = b10* xA[0]+ b11 *xA[1]+ b12*xA[2]- a11*yA[1] - a12*yA[2]; // 1st 2nd order
    y2 = y2/a10;    // is this necessary? without fixed point its 1/1
    yA[0] = y2;

    y = b20* xB[0]+ b21 *xB[1]+ b22*xB[2]- a21*yB[1] - a22*yB[2];                       //2nd 2nd order
    y = y/a20;    // same for this one
    yB[0] = y;

    xA[0] = res;                                                     // 1st 2nd order delays
    xA[2] = xA[1];
    xA[1] = xA[0];

    yA[2] = yA[1];
    yA[1] = yA[0];

    xB[0] = res;                                                    // 2d 2nd order delays
    xB[2] = xB[1];
    xB[1] = xB[0];

    yB[2] = yB[1];
    yB[1] = yB[0];

    res = (short)(y >>14);                                          // divided by 16384 or 2^14     voltage = y>>14
    voltage = (double) res * 1000 * VREF / (MAX_VALUE_ADC + 1);     // Measured voltage in Volts.

    BinaryValue =  voltage*((MAX_VALUE_DAC)/(VCC))*0.001*CAL_DAC ;      // Bitvalue
    DACB.CH0DATA = BinaryValue ;                                    //write &USBDataIn to DAC (PIN A10)
    while (!DACB.STATUS & DAC_CH0DRE_bm);
```

Comment: Why does your integer code not seem to work?  Be specific.

Comment: I'm assuming overflow issues from what i've read online. and i'm unsure if multiplying the a10 to b22 by 2^15 is the right way to do it. as this is just one of the ways to do it that i've found mentioned online.

Regards Chris

- Edit  The coefficients a11 and a21 don't even fit in a 16 bit int if i multiply by 2^15. Which i'm assuming is part of the problem

Comment: Chriserke, you don't want your real-time operation cast your `double` to `int32_t`. Scale **up** (and round) your coefficients (by a factor or 16384) first.  In the real-time operation, it should be only `int32_t` times `int32_t` into an `int32_t` result.  and that result should be rounded (by adding 8192 *or* add the bits dropped in the previous sample, if you want this quantization noise-shaped) and shifted right by 14 bits.  is your compiler smart enough that the division operation `y2 = y2/a10;` is actually `y2 >>= 14;`?

Comment: when i get an hour later today, i will write for you a simple fixed-point **Direct Form 1** biquad sample processing loop in C.  it only needs about 8 lines of code.

Comment: That would be great. then i will work that into my code and if you would be willing to give it another look over, then i'd be delighted.

Kind regards Chris.

Comment: sorry, at the moment i have run outa time.  but we've been here before.  [take a look at this previous post from me](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/best-implementation-of-a-real-time-fixed-point-iir-filter-with-constant-coeffic/21800#21800)

Comment: Took a quick peek but it was a little hard to understand due to different naming and some other stuff. it's getting late for me 3am by now and i've got a family gathering tommorow so i'll get back to it tommorow evening. Regards Chris

Comment: Ok i added the edit. I was a little excited with the help i've been getting and fired up so i took my laptop to the gathering and sneakily did some editing.
I'd appreciate if you'd look it over.

Answer (score 2):

A few points to consider

1. Fixed point DSP is hard. Unless you absolutely cant afford it, try to do whole thing in 32-bit floating point
2. Assuming you can't you need to manage clipping results and state variable, quantization noise, limit cycles, coefficient quantization, etc.
3. You do this be carefully choosing representation of in terms number of bits and scaling factor for each individual variable. A good method for this the "Q" notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format) (which I think RBJ calls)
4. C is a not a great language for this since its lacking native support for the most basic fixed point multiply function. Most embedded processor do support them through some sort of intrinsic or fake library call. Grab your processor and/or compiler manual and look for things like "fractional multiply", "fractional data" "rounding behavior" "overlfow/underflow" "accumulator" behavior etc.
5. Understand your requirements: what noise level can you tolerate, how sensitive are too occasional clipping, does the passband actually need to be at 0dB or can you downscale a bit? What's your MIPS budget ? The exact requirements will have significant impact and how you would write the code. Good news is: you really don't need much memory at all.
6. Your specific example: with 16-bits for the coefficients, you are getting a fair bit of coefficient quantification especially on the zeros. This means that your cutoff frequency and passband gain will be slightly off, which may or may not be a problem
7. Your code as written isn't really fixed point. You keep the state variables as doubles and so the compiler will simply promote all ints to doubles before the multiply and then truncate the final result down to int_16 when assigning to the output variable.
8. Get rid of the divides. They don't do anything useful.
9. "If" statements can be VERY expensive on processors with a deep pipeline. Try to manage clipping through proper scaling of all variables and avoid the "if" statements all together.
10. First thing I would look for is whether the processor or compiler supports a 32-bit fractional multiply at a responsable cost. This multiplies two 32-bit numbers and keeps 32 MSBs of the 64-bit result. Then I'd keep the coefficients in Q30.1, the state variables in Q28.3 and scale the final result back down to Q15.0.
11. If available, set rounding mode to "round towards zero", that's slightly more noisy but guarantees to eliminate any limit cycles.

More good reading

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: Hello, This is done on a Xmega chip where 32bits take about 4 times the amount of time a 16 bit takes with no floating point processor. As for passband gain its specified at +1 and -4 throughout the entire passband and -3db at 500hz.As for the states, i should change those to ints as well in the 3rd example code? Lastly a designated dsp is not used but a all in 1 microcontroller with adc and dac.

Comment: Does the processor support fractional data types and fractional multiplies? I suggested you keep the states in Q28.3. If you don't know what that is, it's probably best to study fixed point math for a bit before starting to write code. You'll need it. I assume the process has a floating point library. Try writing it all in 32-bit floats and benchmark it. If that fits your MIPS budget, its by far the easiest way to go

Comment: The very first code i posted is in floating point which does not reach the speed. Thus going for fixed point in which shifting is faster than multiplying for my microcontroller i believe. Also there are no libraries for math used

Comment: I understand what for example Q1.14 is or 28.3 its 1int bit 14 fractions and 28int bits3 fractions i don't know how to correctly implement it however which is why i am struggling

Comment: Your first code is in  64-bit double precision. Turn it into 32-bit single precision (use data type "float"), unroll the loops, get rid of the divides and check whether this is fast enough. If not, check whether your processor or compiler support fractional multiplies

Comment: Hello,
I appreciate the help. My microcontroller does support 8bit fractional multiplies however this is written in assembly and i have no knowledge of this.
As for changing the first code. Optimizing it might make it a bit faster but the last time i tried it i didn't even get close. And i'd really like to learn how to implement fixed point as i believe this would help me in the future.
Kind regards Chris

Comment: @hilmarr I've changed the states and removed the clipping if check statements. I've also changed the way i do the math now using the adc res value instead of the voltage value. At the bottom i then tried to cast the res value back to a voltage which i then push to the DAC. The code can be seen in the 4th bit of code at the bottom. Does this look a bit more like what u meant?

Comment: Look, you should test your code by feeding it a known test vector and comparing the output to the known result. If it matches:great. If not you need to go through it line by line and compare what you get to what you think it should be.  Break it down into smaller steps: start with a pass through. Then do a simple gain stage, Then do a first order low pass filter,  and work your way up there. I understand your pain, but code snippets on the internet aren't likely to get you there,

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply 2 16-bit numbers (int16_t or S.15), the result requires a 32-bit variable (int32_t or S.31), and the 2 pre-scaling values, if any, add.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the tip. I've added my fixed point attempt. i used 16bits ints and multipled my coefficients by 2^14 because with 2^15 it won't fit in a 16 bits int. 
Would you mind having a look to see if this is what u meant?

King regards Chris

Comment: hot, he ain't doing S.31.  he's doing S17.14 .  also C does not automatically extend word width.  we gotta be careful.  Chriserke needs to scale up all coefficients by $2^{14}$ and do all of the fixed-point arithmetic in `int32_t` and scale the result down by $2^{-14}$ by shifting the result to the right by 14 bits.  some form of rounding (or better yet, fraction saving or noise shaping) should be done before shifting right by 14 bits.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson i've sacled up the coefficients in my edit where i included the fixed point attempt. However i don't think i've done the actual arithmic in 32 bit but in 16 bit instead. However im unfamiliar with rounding, fraction saving and noise shaping.

Comment: but `xA[0]` is a `double`, not an `int32_t`.  what's going on there?

Comment: you know what rounding is.  but i will demonstrate a simple fraction saving (which is first-order noise shaping) and with only 16/32 bit precision, you're gonna need some noise shaping if you wanna eliminate some limit cycles and other nasties.

Comment: and this line:  `voltage = y*0.00006103515;// divided by 16384 or 2^14` is **not** fixed-point processing.

Comment: xA gets the voltage reading of the Adc which gets the input of 1v sine wave. i could add the entire code but i've omitted the adc setup and other stuff as i didn't think this was relevant to my question.

How would you suggets i change that line as i thought dividing the end result by the amount that i've multiplied is a must?

Comment: but your ADC does **not** return `double`, does it?

Comment: voltage = (double) res * 1000 * VREF / (MAX_VALUE_ADC + 1);     // Measured voltage in Volts.

Where res is the adc value in int between 0-2047

Comment: i thought you wanted to do fixed-point DSP.  does your processor that is doing this filtering, does that processor have floating-point capability or not?  **why** do you need to do *anything* in fixed-point?

Comment: it does but it is much slower and i cannot get my required speed using floating point.
As it has to simulate floats

Comment: so your `res` value appears to be an 11-bit number.  the fact that it is not a 16-bit number can be used to your advantage to get 5 more bits of precision out of your coefficients.  that can help.  does `res=0` really mean zero?  or does `res=1024` really mean zero?  i.e., is this a *"constant offset"* signed value or an unsigned value that is never meant to go negative?  and is your DAC using the same numbering scheme?

Comment: it's probably because it does all the floating point in software **emulating** a floating-point ALU.  so let's rewrite this whole thing to do fixed-point **purely** and correctly.

Comment: I believe 0 is actually 0 as i've defined the max value to be 2047 which is roughly 2 volt

Comment: I could add the entire code with initialisation of the adc and dac which might be useful to see. if you'd like.

Comment: i don't care about initialization.  i just wanted to know about the nature of the numbers coming from that ADC and going to the DAC.  so your ADC and DAC values are ***unsigned*** non-negative values, correct?  is your DAC also having the same range: 0 to 2047?

Comment: There are no negative voltages going into the adc or out of the dac. just between 0 and 2. And both values are int16_t

Comment: and you write the same-scaled numbers to the DAC, right?  `0` to the DAC means 0 volts and `2047` to the DAC means virtually 2 volts, right?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/05b2f5805f3ea51ad317109248335110 this is what i've done to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Forgot to add these, these are the values of the ADC and DAC
https://gyazo.com/629cfb004f4d660ecd7dc89e0042ac59