# How to interpret integer coefficients for a filter generated by Matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, dsp-core

I have always used high-performance 32-bit microcontrollers with hardware FPU support. To calculate the coefficients of digital filters, I used the fdatool package in Matlab. I used single-precision floating point coefficients for digital filters. Next, in accordance with this figure, I implemented digital filters:
[image]
Moreover, sometimes it was possible to do a little optimization, for example with the LP filter I did this:

```
void lp_filter (float *x ,float *y,float *aa ,float g ,float vh)
{
    x[2]=x[1];
    x[1]=x[0];
    x[0]=vh*g;
    y[2]=y[1];
    y[1]=y[0];
    y[0]=(x[0] + x[1] + x[1] + x[2] - aa[0]*y[1] - aa[1]*y[2]); //b0=1 b1=2 b2=1
}
```

I knew that the b coefficients would always be (1,2,1), so I simply could not do unnecessary multiplication operations. Perhaps the compiler itself could do this, but I'm not sure about that...

Now I have a low-performance 32-bit microcontroller without an FPU. I wanted to implement digital filters, but with integer mathematics. The fdatool package also allows you to calculate integer filter coefficients, but I don’t understand how to use them... For example, here are the coefficients for a 500Hz 6th order low pass filter:

```
#define MWSPT_NSEC 7
const int NL[MWSPT_NSEC] = { 1,3,1,3,1,3,1 };
const int32_T NUM[MWSPT_NSEC][3] = {
  {
     265839664,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647,  2147483647,  2147483647 
  },
  {
     209661133,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647,  2147483647,  2147483647 
  },
  {
     186862344,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647,  2147483647,  2147483647 
  },
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  }
};
const int DL[MWSPT_NSEC] = { 1,3,1,3,1,3,1 };
const int32_T DEN[MWSPT_NSEC][3] = {
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647, -2147483648,  1483049895 
  },
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647, -2024667000,   715827883 
  },
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647, -1804502424,   404468153 
  },
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  }
};
```

I choose the format of the filter coefficients as 32 bit signed integer. If I follow the same implementation I used for floating point, the input value may overflow 32 bits... Perhaps I need to use the coefficients as 16 bit signed integers or store the results in 64 bit registers?
I tried using the int64_t format, but the filters don't work correctly. I can't understand why...
Also, in the integer implementation of digital filters, I don’t understand how I should work with the final result? For example, how can I understand where the comma would be if it were a float number?

---

For digital filters I used single precision floating point coefficients. Here is an example of such coefficients that I obtained in Matlab:

```
#define MWSPT_NSEC 3
const int NL[MWSPT_NSEC] = { 1,3,1 };
const real32_T NUM[MWSPT_NSEC][3] = {
  {
    0.01185768284,              0,              0 
  },
  {
                1,              2,              1 
  },
  {
                1,              0,              0 
  }
};
const int DL[MWSPT_NSEC] = { 1,3,1 };
const real32_T DEN[MWSPT_NSEC][3] = {
  {
                1,              0,              0 
  },
  {
                1,   -1.669203162,   0.7166338563 
  },
  {
                1,              0,              0 
  }
};
```

Based on these coefficients, I implemented a digital filter like this:

```
float sek1_x[3],sek1_y[3],sek1_a[3]={1,   -1.669203162,   0.7166338563},sek1_b[3]={1,              2,              1};
void lp_filter (float *x ,float *y,float *aa ,float *bb ,float g ,float in)
{
    x[2]=x[1];
    x[1]=x[0];
    x[0]=in*g;
    y[2]=y[1];
    y[1]=y[0];
    y[0]=(x[0]*bb[0] + x[1]*bb[1] + x[2]*bb[2] - aa[1]*y[1] - aa[2]*y[2]);
} 
//Calling the filter function:
lp_filter(sek1_x,sek1_y,sek1_a,sek1_b,0.01185768284,adc_res);
```

The fdatool package also allows you to calculate integer filter coefficients. Here is an example of such coefficients for exactly the same filter, which I obtained in Matlab:

```
#define MWSPT_NSEC 3
const int NL[MWSPT_NSEC] = { 1,3,1 };
const int32_T NUM[MWSPT_NSEC][3] = {
  {
      25464180,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647,  2147483647,  2147483647 
  },
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  }
};
const int DL[MWSPT_NSEC] = { 1,3,1 };
const int32_T DEN[MWSPT_NSEC][3] = {
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  },
  {
    2147483647, -2147483648,  1538959525 
  },
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 
  }
};
```

Here is the code for implementing a digital filter with integer coefficients based on my code (as well as the figure I provided above) for implementing floating point filters:

```
int32_t sek1_x[3], sek1_y[3];
int32_t sek1_a[3] = { 2147483647, -2147483648, 1538959525 };
int32_t sek1_b[3] = { 2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647 };

void lp_filter(int32_t *x, int32_t *y, int32_t *aa, int32_t *bb, int32_t g, int32_t in) {
    x[2] = x[1];
    x[1] = x[0];
    x[0] = ((int64_t)in * g) >> 31; // Scaling by shifting

    y[2] = y[1];
    y[1] = y[0];
    
    // Perform the filtering with scaling
    y[0] = (((int64_t)x[0] * bb[0] + (int64_t)x[1] * bb[1] + (int64_t)x[2] * bb[2] - (int64_t)aa[1] * y[1] - (int64_t)aa[2] * y[2])*2147483647) >> 31;
}

// Calling the filter function:
lp_filter(sek1_x, sek1_y, sek1_a, sek1_b, 25464180, adc_res);
```

I'm not sure that this will work, since I don't understand what part of the data is needed for, namely these lines:

```
const int DL[MWSPT_NSEC] = { 1,3,1 };
const int32_T DEN[MWSPT_NSEC][3] = {
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 <- this line
  },
  {
    2147483647, -2147483648,  1538959525 
  },
  {
    2147483647,           0,           0 <- this line
  }
};
```

I also don’t understand how I can properly monitor overflow. I did shifts to try to avoid overflow, but I'm not sure if it's correct...
Does anyone have any ideas on how to correctly use integer coefficients generated by matlab to implement digital filters?

---

I wrote an example from the information that I understood, but I made a mistake somewhere, but I don’t understand where...
Source code with float filter implementation (6th order low pass filter and 2nd order high pass filter):

```
float   lp500_sek1_x[3],lp500_sek1_y[3],lp500_sek1_a[2]={-1.833933353,   0.8860449791},
        lp500_sek2_x[3],lp500_sek2_y[3],lp500_sek2_a[2]={-1.669203162,   0.7166338563},
        lp500_sek3_x[3],lp500_sek3_y[3],lp500_sek3_a[2]={-1.586906791,   0.6319990754},
        hp5_sek1_x[3],hp5_sek1_y[3],hp5_sek1_a[2]={-1.998889327,   0.9988899231};

//Calling filters
lp_filter(lp500_sek1_x,lp500_sek1_y,lp500_sek1_a,0.01302789338,((float)res_adc));
lp_filter(lp500_sek2_x,lp500_sek2_y,lp500_sek2_a,0.01185768284,lp500_sek1_y[0]);
lp_filter(lp500_sek3_x,lp500_sek3_y,lp500_sek3_a,0.01127306558,lp500_sek2_y[0]);
hp_filter(hp5_sek1_x,hp5_sek1_y,hp5_sek1_a,0.9994447827,lp500_sek3_y[0]);

//Filter functions
void lp_filter (float *x ,float *y,float *aa ,float g ,float vh)
{
    x[2]=x[1];
    x[1]=x[0];
    x[0]=vh*g;
    y[2]=y[1];
    y[1]=y[0];
    y[0]=(x[0] + x[1]+x[1] + x[2] - aa[0]*y[1] - aa[1]*y[2]); //b0=1 b1=2 b2=1
}
void hp_filter (float *x ,float *y,float *aa ,float g ,float vh)
{
    x[2]=x[1];
    x[1]=x[0];
    x[0]=vh*g;
    y[2]=y[1];
    y[1]=y[0];
    y[0]=(x[0] - (x[1]+x[1]) + x[2] - aa[0]*y[1] - aa[1]*y[2]); //b0=1 b1=-2 b2=1
}
```

Source code with an integer implementation of the same filters (6th order low-pass filter and 2nd order high-pass filter):

```
int32_t ilp500_sek1_a[2]={-1969170942, 951383551},
        ilp500_sek2_a[2]={-1792293247, 769479743},
        ilp500_sek3_a[2]={-1703928191, 678603839},
        ihp5_sek1_a[2]={-2146291070,  1072549887},
        ilp6_sek1_a[2]={-2145098367, 1071359231};

int64_t ilp500_sek1_x[3],ilp500_sek1_y[3],
        ilp500_sek2_x[3],ilp500_sek2_y[3],
        ilp500_sek3_x[3],ilp500_sek3_y[3],
        ihp5_sek1_x[3],ihp5_sek1_y[3],
        ilp6_sek1_x[3],ilp6_sek1_y[3];

//Calling filters
lp_filter_int(ilp500_sek1_x,ilp500_sek1_y,ilp500_sek1_a,13988593,((int64_t)res_adc));
lp_filter_int(ilp500_sek2_x,ilp500_sek2_y,ilp500_sek2_a,12732089,ilp500_sek1_y[0]);
lp_filter_int(ilp500_sek3_x,ilp500_sek3_y,ilp500_sek3_a,12104361,ilp500_sek2_y[0]);
hp_filter_int(ihp5_sek1_x,ihp5_sek1_y,ihp5_sek1_a,1073145662,ilp500_sek3_y[0]);

//Filter functions
void lp_filter_int (int64_t *x ,int64_t *y,int32_t *aa ,int32_t g ,int64_t vh)
{
    x[2]=x[1];
    x[1]=x[0];
    x[0]=(vh*(int64_t)g)>>30;
    y[2]=y[1];
    y[1]=y[0];
    y[0]=((x[0]*(int64_t)0x3FFFFFFF) + (x[1]*(int64_t)0x7FFFFFFF) + (x[2]*(int64_t)0x3FFFFFFF) - ((int64_t)aa[0]*y[1]) - ((int64_t)aa[1]*y[2]))>>30; //b0=1 b1=2 b2=1
}
void hp_filter_int (int64_t *x ,int64_t *y,int32_t *aa ,int32_t g ,int64_t vh)
{
    x[2]=x[1];
    x[1]=x[0];
    x[0]=(vh*(int64_t)g)>>30;
    y[2]=y[1];
    y[1]=y[0];
    y[0]=((x[0]*(int64_t)0x3FFFFFFF) - (x[1]*(int64_t)0x7FFFFFFF) + (x[2]*(int64_t)0x3FFFFFFF) - ((int64_t)aa[0]*y[1]) - ((int64_t)aa[1]*y[2]))>>30; //b0=1 b1=-2 b2=1
}
```

After the integer low-pass filter, I see a similar signal as after the float low-pass filter, but after the high-pass filter everything breaks down... I can’t understand what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Fixed point processing is complicated. Most people use the so-called "Q" notation to track scale factors and avoid overflows. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format) . You need to track the scale for EVERY state variable and intermediate result. Stage ordering and pole zero pairing can make a significant difference for SNR. Stay away from Direct Form II and Transposed Form I . Make sure you implement proper rounding.

Comment: Looking a little closer, I can see one problem.  You're using Q1.31 and you **should** be using Q2.30 instead.  Your $a_1$ coefficient (which gets scaled to be in `aa[1]`) can range from -2 to +2 in a biquad.  So your integer value of your coefficients should be scaled up by $2^{30}$ and not by $2^{31}$.  Do you understand this?

Comment: My goodness, I knew that MATLAB had a C code generator, but I didn't know the quality of the code was so poor.  They could do ***far*** better.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson As you say, the value of my float coefficients, which was generated by mallab, is in the range -2 to +2. If I want to convert these coefficients to integer, then I allocate 1 bit for the sign, and float=2 becomes equal to 2^31, which will give me coverage of the entire range, right? That is, for my example, the float array a={1,-1.669203162,0.7166a338563} will become the integer array a={1073741824,-1792293247,769479744}.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson
But there are two problems that I can't seem to figure out: 1. How do I control overflow? If my range is -2..2, overflows will happen all the time... 2. What should I do with integer coefficients for example b={1,2,1}, I will be forced to convert them to integer and do operations that I can avoid in float for speed (for example, multiplying by 1).

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson Those integer coefficients that you see in my example, I did not convert them myself, they were generated by Matlab. And as far as I understand, he himself normalized them to the range -1 to 1.

Comment: Well, that's a problem in general.  I use MATLAB a lot.  I complain a lot about MATLAB regarding the hard-wired index origin and some other dumb mistakes that should have been fixed 30 years ago, when I first brought them up (I actually had a phone call with Cleve Moler about it in the 1990s).  Anyway, this is one more dumb thing to complain about.  In a 2nd-order IIR filter, the denominator coefficient $a_0=1$ and the other two coefficients must be relative to that.  And the range of $a_1$ is $-2 \le a_1 \le +2$.  You need to have two bits to the left of the binary point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lotta detail in the question.

I have done a hella lotta fixed-point DSP in my day.  Both with a fixed-point DSP (56K) and with an integer CPU such as the 68K but also in generic C code.  I posted an [answer about specific C code](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/best-implementation-of-a-real-time-fixed-point-iir-filter-with-constant-coeffic/21811#21811) that does a biquad in fixed point and uses noise-shaping at the sole quantization point.  You should look at it.

Here is the main principle.  You saw a comment refer to the "Q" notation.  E.g. Q2.14 means a 16-bit fixed-point number with 2 bits to the left of the binary point and 14 to the right.  What this really means is that the 16-bit integer has an integer value (this is the value that the C program sees) that is scaled up by a factor of $2^{14}$.  This doesn't really matter for the signal; whatever scaling of the signal in the input is the same scaling for the output.  But it ***does*** matter for the coefficients.  Every coefficient is represented as an integer that is $2^{14}$ times larger than the *actual* numerical value of the coefficient.

So, when you **integer** multiply that coefficient times another value (like a signal or a state), the result will be $2^{14}$ times bigger than it should be.  So you'll have to shift it 14 bits to the right to scale it with $2^{-14}$ and undo the scaling of the coefficient necessary to make it an integer.  This shifting right causes 14 bits to fall offa the edge, which is quantization error.  Noise shaping can help minimize the consequences of that quantization.

With 32 bits, the quantization error will be much smaller in effect.

So you have to deal with the range of your coefficients, so you know how much to scale them.  For a biquad, we know the denominator coefficients will have absolute value of less than 2.  So we can represent those coefficients well as Q2.30 fixed-point values.  So using `int32_t` as your coefficients and `int64_t` as your accumulator, then after multiplying, you will have to shift the 64-bit value 30 bits to the right.

Besides noise-shaping (in this specific case, *"fraction saving"* is the noise shaping), there are some other useful tricks in fixed-point DSP.  Another trick is to use the **Direct Form 1** and do **not** use **Direct Form II**.  The reasons why are two-fold:  First the DF1 has only one point of quantization.  And second, the DF1 puts the effect of the zeros before the poles, so in a high-Q filter, there is attenuation (from a zero) that will occur before there is gain (from the pole).  This means that unnecessary internal overflow is avoided.  And keeping a 64-bit accumulator and adding up all 5 values before quantization allows you to quantize after the addition.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed explanation. I just don't understand some points. Why do I need to select the number form as Q2.30? I allocate one bit for the sign, and the remaining 31 I can use for my range of numbers. For example, if I want to express the numbers from -2 to 2. I can use like 2^31 = 2.

Comment: I also don’t understand what the right thing to do is: convert my float coefficients myself or have Matlab do this work? For example, if my original float array was a={1,-1.669203162,0.7166338563}, then the integer array would become a={1073741824,-1792293247,769479744}. But Matlab gives me a={2147483647,-2147483648, 1538959525}.

Comment: ***//"if I want to express the numbers from -2 to 2. I can use like 2^31 = 2."//*** - - - - - - really?  You better look closely into that.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, and I want to use the Q2.30 format, then I give the two most significant bits for the integer part and the sign, and the remaining 30 for the fractional part. So? My float array a={1,-1.669203162,0.7166338563}, would it be a={0x4000 0000,0xEAD4 397F,0x2DDD 543F}?

Comment: I think so.  It looks correct.  I am not converting the hex, but it looks right.  Now, when you shift right, instead of shifting right 31 bits (`>>31`), you will be shifting right by 30 bits.

Comment: In decimal it would be {1,073,741,824, -1,792,293,247, 769,479,743}. Regarding the shift, I also want to understand when it needs to be done? Every time I multiply by a factor? Or at the very end, when I “added and subtracted the entire value with coefficients a and b”?

Comment: And I also don’t understand what to do with the result? After all, the result may be greater than the range -2..+2

Comment: This is the point: You don't have to worry about the scaling of the signal. Assume it's the same before and after the multiplication.  The coefficients are $2^{30}$ times too big. That means the results of multiplying coefficient to signal will be $2^{30}$ times too big.  So you have to eventually divide by $2^{30}$.  That's the same as multiplying by $2^{-30}$.  That's the same as shifting the bits right by 30 bits.

Comment: Now there is this thing we learned in school called the Association Property  $$ ab + ac =  a(b+c)  $$ so it doesn't make a mathematical difference whether you right-shift each product and add them or if you add them first and the right-shift the sum.  But numerically, adding the 64-bit intermediate products first and right-shifting the sum will result in $\frac15$ of the quantization noise power

Comment: I meant to say "Associative Property" and more specifically I mean $$2^{-30} b + 2^{-30} c = 2^{-30} (b+c)$$.  So add them first.  Then quantize.

Comment: Oh, and you may have to explicitly clip the result just before right-shifting.

Comment: Yes I understood that, thanks! There is still one more point that I don’t understand and that worries me: how can I find the whole part of the signal at the output? My range is -2..+2. The output signal can be greater than +2 and also less than -2.

Comment: How do I understand where the bit responsible for the sign will be?

Comment: Is the output signal in the same format as is the input signal?  It doesn't matter what scaling factor you apply to them.  Just make sure it's the same.  You say your *" range is -2..+2"*.  Are you sure?  Don't you have integer values coming out of the ADC?  Don't you input integer values to the DAC?  This issue of Q2.30 need apply ***only*** to the coefficients.

Comment: I meant the output signal after the filters. It can already be greater than the range -2 to +2, and it can also be negative. I'm trying to understand how I can correctly find the whole part of the signal after the filters without losing the sign?

Comment: red, ***that scaling doesn't matter to the signal as long as you're consistent***.  Those numbers are ***signed integers***, with a range of $-2^{31}$ to $+2^{31}-1$.  This Q2.30 scaling is ***only*** for the coefficients.  *Those* are real numbers between $-2$ and $+2-2^{-30}$ but are scaled up by a factor of $2^{30}$ and rounded to the nearest integer.  Got that?

Comment: I'm trying to understand... My coefficients are currently in Q2.30 format. Next, I multiply them by the corresponding input arrays and output arrays (y[0]=(x[0]*bb[0] + x[1]*bb[1] + x[2]*bb[2] - aa [1]*y[1] - aa[2]*y[2]). The result will be stored in the variable int64_t. Next y[0], I shift to the right by 30. I tried to do everything that I understood, but I get an error... and I don't understand why... I added an example in the first post. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you're doing it right.  There shouldn't be an overflow after adding those five terms, but maybe after you right shift 30 bits, you should test if it's bigger than 0x7FFFFFFF or smaller than 0x80000000 and clip then values if they are.  Do that to the 64 bit value right after right shifting.

Comment: I realized what my mistake was. I'm writing in C for a stm32 microcontroller, when I shifted numbers 30 bits to the right, I shifted them with a sign and correspondingly lost their sign. You can replace the right shift by 30 bits with division by 2^30, then the sign will be preserved.

Comment: I've been experimenting all weekend with integer filters and various integer coefficients. Matlab (fdatool package) generates coefficients for the filter always using gain and because of this, after I multiply the input signal by gain, I also need to move it to the right by 30 bits and I lose the bits after the decimal point. And then I also move the output signal to the right by 30 bits and again lose the values after the decimal point. As a result, such a filter becomes inoperative. I don't understand how to do it without losing the signal.

Comment: For example, the filter that was given in the example (6-order low-pass filter at 150 Hz. Sampling frequency 4 kHz), if a constant signal of 2048 is applied to it, after 1 section there will be 87, after 2 sections 3 and after 3 sections 0.

Comment: The ANSI C language standard is that right-shifting `unsigned` is Logical Shift Right, which shifts in a 0 on the left.  Shifting a signed integer right is supposed to use Arithmetic Shift Right which sign-extends and copies the MSB .  And division is normally a slow, multi-instruction operation.  You shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Now instead of just losing the bits that fall offa the edge, you should use ***fraction saving***, which is the simplest noise shaping.  You get no quantization noise at DC.  But it increases the quantization noise at Nyquist.  I think I pointed to a reference before.

Comment: I understood the idea of fraction saving. I get a slightly better result with a constant signal, but it still doesn’t work. Perhaps because I have two left shifts by 30. The first is when I multiply the input signal by gain, and after I have calculated y[0]. After I added fraction saving after 1 section I get 90, after 2 sections 6 and after 3 sections 0.